# Pixel C no longer connecting to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, google-pixel

The Pixel C (serial # 620*******) is no longer connecting to wifi. We have 3 wifi networks and it does not connect to any of them (it did before). It vacillates between saying "Obtaining IP address" and "Ip configuration failure". I've tried "forgetting" each of the wifi connections and reentering the password, but this does not help. Also tried restarting the device.

I discovered this on Tuesday morning, coming back from the holiday. During that time the device's battery went dead. Not sure if that is related or not. The battery is fully charged now.

What can be done?

Edit:
Just noticed the clock has been reset to Jan 1, 2000. Fixing that fixed the wifi problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our network has a security feature that checks any connecting device for a correct date and doesn't allow connection if the date is not correct.